# Meaning of "A matter of worse or of better"

Tags: meaning-in-context

After listening to **The Bed Song** from Amanda Palmer multiple times, I can't seem to be able to translate "Is it **a matter of worse or of better**?" in my head.

> And I finally ask you, what was the matter?
>
> Was it a matter of worse or of better?

Is it kind of a poetic licence for "**for the worse or for the better**" (but it doesn't seem to make much sense either to me) or does it have another clearer meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is a reference to the saying:

> *for better or for worse*

which is a standard phrase in many marriage vows. Here is a longer version of a typical marriage vow:

> *to have and to hold, for better or for worse, for richer or for poorer, in sickness and in health, til death do us part*

Essentially, it means you'll stick with your spouse in both good times and in bad times.

It sounds like the person is maybe asking, "Why did we break up? Were things getting better between us? Or worse?" but doing it in a clever way that references standard marriage vows while getting the words *matter* and *better* aligned.

Lyric interpretation is [off-topic](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302), so I won't delve into it much more deeply than that.